# Inner join two tables with date results

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

The result should show me which active clients have not been visited the place the last 15 days, according to todays' date.

The two tables I have are:

```
**Table: subscription**
------------------------------------
id | client_id | expiring
------------------------------------
1  |    253    | 2018-03-22 00:00:00
2  |    265    | 2018-02-14 00:00:00
3  |    274    | 2018-05-29 00:00:00
------------------------------------

**Table: checkins**
------------------------------------
id | client_id | date
------------------------------------
1  |    253    | 2018-01-18 13:18:21
2  |    265    | 2017-12-14 16:18:23
3  |    274    | 2018-02-25 15:01:09
------------------------------------
```

So the end result should show me 1 result with client_id 253

Comment: your example is not clear  ..

Comment: What's today's date?

Comment: @Strawberry today's date is always today for example 2018-02-26 so if i run the report tomorrow should be 2018-02-27

Comment: @scaisEdge please let me know what to explain

Comment: So the end result won't necessarily be 253

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select distinct s.client_id from subscription s
where s.expiring >= current_date()
and not exists (
  select 1 from checkins c
  where datediff(current_date(), c.date) <= 14
  and c.client_id = s.client_id
)
```

The first condition in the where clause limits the result to active clients and the second condition excludes clients that have been visited within the last 14 days.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b850f)

Comment: What happens if there are no checkins for a client?

Comment: This one shows me lots of rows for the result and I can see client_id appearing more than once so for instance client_id 4 appears in the results 65 times which are the total of his checkins. At which part of your query should put a limit one for each client_id ?

Comment: Ok so from what I understood now it returns me all clients (only once per client_id) that have checkins more than 15 days from current date but it also returns clients that have checked in yesterday for example. so i need to exclude those clients I only want to return clients that havent checked-in the last 15 days.

Comment: @Andr Please try it now. I hope I got it right this time :)

Comment: The WHERE clause can be optimized

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sure it can. Feel free to add a better answer or edit mine if you want to; I haven't really got time to improve upon it.

Comment: Well something like `where c.date >= current_date() - INTERVAL 14 DAY` could use an index

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Here is the query to extract the specific result

```
select * from checkins t1 join subscription t2 on t1.client_id=t2.client_id where
date(t2.expiring) >= date(NOW()) and datediff(current_date(), date(t1.date)) > 14;
```

Comment: You need to add tests for  'the last 15 days' part of the question.

Comment: exactly this query does not have anything related to the 15 days

Comment: Hi question is not clear so i got confused. Now i have updated the query bro. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks but also the return has many rows and each client_id appears more than once so how can i limit to be once per client_id?

Comment: You can group by client_id. For each client id you will get only one result

Answer (score 0):

I have simulate your both table as below:

```
mysql> select * from t03;
+------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | client_id | expiring            |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
|    1 |       253 | 2018-03-22 00:00:00 |
|    2 |       265 | 2018-02-14 00:00:00 |
|    3 |       274 | 2018-05-29 00:00:00 |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t04;
+------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | client_id | date                |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
|    3 |       274 | 2018-02-25 15:01:09 |
|    2 |       265 | 2017-12-14 16:18:23 |
|    1 |       253 | 2018-01-18 13:18:21 |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
```

and all your need is as following code.

```
select * from t04 where client_id in (select client_id from t03 where expiring > current_date()) and datediff(current_date() ,date) > 15  ;
```

and then your will got result as below:

```
+------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | client_id | date                |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
|    1 |       253 | 2018-01-18 13:18:21 |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
```